# Multiline regexp with <? and ?>?

Tags: regex, lines

here is my code :

```
<html>
titi
<?

print "toto"+"<br>"

?>
<html>
```

and i  want only the lines between the `<? and ?>` the only regexp thaht i've found was :

```
<?.*\n*?\?>
```

but it lacks the first `<?`

so if anyone have any idea it drives me nuts ...
Regards and thanks for all people.
Bussiere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the first `?`:

```
<\?.*\n*?\?>
```

This regex would be more robust I think:

```
<\?.*?\?>
```

(specify the multiline option, so `.` will match newlines also)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a backslash before the first question mark (also you should use the regex's multiline mode):

```
<\?.*?\?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the first ?

```
<\?.*\n*?\?>
```